# Item location in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml, menu, navigation-drawer

I use template Navigation Drawer. I can add items from res, but when I add items from my DB, then my items add to end Navigation Drawer.

This code in my activity:

```
        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

    while (storesCursor.moveToNext()){
        menu.add(R.id.nav_group_stores, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, storesCursor.getString(storesCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_AUTHORIZATION_DOMAIN)));
    }
    storesCursor.close();
```

And this code in my menu.xml:

```
<item android:title="@string/nav_title_stores">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/nav_group_stores">
        </group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/add_store"
            android:title="Add new store">

        </item>
    </menu>
</item>
```

My problem: Items add to end in Navigation Drawer.

What I want?
I want add my items in middle between "nav_title_stores" and "add_store".

How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it have add method with index? So it can insert in the middle.

Comment: Although I directly point out an items is added to the end. I can't understand, what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `add_store` menu items.
2. Add new menu item from DB.
3. Add `add_store` menu items

like this:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

SubMenu titlesMenu = menu.getItem(0).getSubMenu();
titlesMenu.removeItem(R.id.add_store);

while (storesCursor.moveToNext()){
    menu.add(R.id.nav_group_stores, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, storesCursor.getString(storesCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_AUTHORIZATION_DOMAIN)));
}
storesCursor.close();

titlesMenu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.add_store, Menu.NONE, "Add new store");
```

Comment: It's almost the right decision, I changed 1 row in your advice:
            
titlesMenu.add()

But nevertheless you helped me.